# Konva js | Line Polygons x, y changes if Transformer changes size

Tags: javascript, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I made an Rectangle with Line so that later progress I can edit its form. Also I wanted to be able to resize this Polygon. If I select it it gets added to a Transformers nodes. The Issue now is that if I scale the Polygon up the x and y of the Polygon also slightly go up. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you for your help !

I have made to pictures so that the Problem is more obvious.

[This is the Picture before scaling and the x, y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McFRL.png)

[This is the Picture after scaling and the x, y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVdMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen because of stroke scaling. You can set `ignoreStroke: true` for transformer to avoid that.

Also, `scaleStrokeEnabled: false` for your `Konva.Line` may work better.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I already found scaleStrokeEnabled: false but ignoreStroke: true was what I was searching for.